# log4j2 external library logs to separate files

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I'm using **log4j2** xml configuration with a **Routing Appender** and a wrapper. I'm passing different appenders to log to different files for different parts of the project. My configuration looks something like this.

```
<Configuration status="WARN">
<Appenders>


    <Routing name="RoutingAppender">

        <Routes pattern="${ctx:logFileName}">
            <Route>
                <RollingFile name="Rolling-${ctx:logFileName}"
                             fileName="logs/${ctx:logFileName}"
                             filePattern="logs/${ctx:logFileName}.%i.log.gz">
                    <PatternLayout pattern="d{ABSOLUTE} %level{length=5} [%thread] %logger{10}.%method:%line-%msg%n"/>
                    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy  size="100 MB" />
                </RollingFile>
            </Route>

            <!-- This route is chosen if ThreadContext has no value for key logFileName} -->
            <Route key="$${ctx:logFileName}">
                <RollingFile name="Rolling-default" fileName="logs/WITHOOUT-THREAD-CONTEXT.log"
                             filePattern="./logs/${date:yyyy-MM}/default-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
                    <PatternLayout>
                        <pattern>%d{ABSOLUTE} %level{length=5} [%thread] %logger{10}.%method:%line-%msg%n</pattern>
                    </PatternLayout>
                    <Policies>
                        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="6" modulate="true" />
                        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
                    </Policies>
                </RollingFile>
            </Route>

        </Routes>
    </Routing>
</Appenders>
```

The problem is, I'm getting external library logs(those without appenders) together with my project logs in the second route, although I want only external logs.

Comment: You should try configuring `Logger` with a `RollingFile Appender`. That should be easy way to do.

Comment: @VikasSachdeva can you please, explain how?

Comment: If your application logs and external library logs both are going on second route, it means you are not clearing setting context lookup variable `logFileName` value.

Comment: @VikasSachdeva your answer actually solved my problem I was just going to upvote it. So you can repost it. P.S. yes, I'm clearing the ThreadContext

Comment: Ok. I have reposted

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use configuration something like below -

```
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>

        <RollingFile name="RollingFile"
                             fileName="logs/${ctx:logFileName}"
                             filePattern="logs/${ctx:logFileName}.%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="d{ABSOLUTE} %level{length=5} [%thread] %logger{10}.%method:%line-%msg%n"/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy  size="100 MB" />
        </RollingFile>

        <RollingFile name="Rolling-default" fileName="logs/WITHOOUT-THREAD-CONTEXT.log"
                             filePattern="./logs/${date:yyyy-MM}/default-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{ABSOLUTE} %level{length=5} [%thread] %logger{10}.%method:%line-%msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="6" modulate="true" />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="application.package" level="info" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="Rolling-default" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

In this configuration, there are 2 loggers. One logger is for your application having root package name  - `application.package`. This package should contain all sub-packages and classes of your application. It will use `RollingFile` `Appender` for logging.

Another is `Root` logger which can be used for logging external libraries i.e. classes which are not in `application.package`. It will use `Rolling-default` `Appender`.

In above configuration, you are setting `fileName` through context lookup so you have to set context value in the beginning otherwise you will get error.